# Is there something like a SinkSource[T]?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I am looking for a `SinkSource` that provides a `Sink` and a `Source`. If an element flows into that `Sink` it should be provided at the corresponding `Source`. The following code shows what I mean:

```
object SinkSource {
  def apply[T] = new {
    def sink: Sink[T] = ???
    def source: Source[T] = ???
  }
}
val flowgraph = FlowGraph { implicit fgb =>
  import FlowGraphImplicits._
  val sinksource = SinkSource[Int]
  Source(1 to 5) ~> sinksource.sink
                    sinksource.source ~> Sink.foreach(print)
}
implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem(name = "System")
implicit val flowMaterializer = FlowMaterializer()
val materializedMap = flowgraph.run()
```

If executed this should print: `12345`
So, does a `SinkSource` exist (haven't seen it in the API) or does anyone know how to implement it?
I should mention that I need distinct access to `Sink` and `Source` so that `Flow` isn't a solution in this particular form:

```
Source(1 to 5) ~> Flow[Int] ~> Sink.foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 1):

As so often, ideas come to mind if question was already asked: It turned out, I don't need a `Sink` and a `Source`, `JunctionInPort` and `JunctionOutPort` are sufficient.
So here it goes:

```
object SinkSource {
  def apply[T](implicit fgb: FlowGraphBuilder) = new SinkSource[T]
}
class SinkSource[T](implicit fgb: FlowGraphBuilder) {
  import FlowGraphImplicits._
  private val merge = Merge[T]
  private val bcast = Broadcast[T]
  Source.empty ~> merge
  merge ~> bcast
  bcast ~> Sink.ignore
  def in: JunctionInPort[T] = merge
  def out: JunctionOutPort[T] = bcast
}
val flowgraph = FlowGraph { implicit fgb =>
  import FlowGraphImplicits._
  val source = Source(1 to 5)
  val sink = Sink.foreach(println)
  val sinkSource = SinkSource[Int]
  source ~> sinkSource.in
            sinkSource.out ~> sink
}
implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem(name = "System")
implicit val flowMaterializer = FlowMaterializer()
val materializedMap = flowgraph.run()
```